# Syntax Error: Token 'em' is an unexpected token at column 4 of the expression

Tags: angularjs

Im getting this error
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'em' is an unexpected token at column 4 of the expression [it em.divider] starting at [em.divider] angular.js:11607
But when i go to the line no 11607 at column 4 of angular.js i see this code

```
 message = prefix + template.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, function(match) {
      var index = +match.slice(1, -1), arg;

      if (index + 2 < templateArgs.length) {
        return toDebugString(templateArgs[index + 2]);
      }
      return match;
    });

    message = message + '\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/' +
      (module ? module + '/' : '') + code;
    for (i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      message = message + (i == 2 ? '?' : '&') + 'p' + (i - 2) + '=' +
        encodeURIComponent(toDebugString(arguments[i]));
    }
    return new ErrorConstructor(message);
  };
```

Comment: The problem is how you call it, not the angular code

Comment: Space betwwen it and em . May be a typo [item.divider]